# Using an array as a counter

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a module that counts how many times each digits shows up in a given number.  The issue I am having is that instead of adding 1 to the array value of the corresponding digit it seems to add 10, that or it concatenates the array's default value ( 0 in this case) although that seems very unlikely.

My module:

```
public class UtilNumber{
    public static int [] Occurence(int nb){
        int temp;
        int [] t = new int [10];

        while (nb !=0){
            temp = nb % 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < t.length ; i++){
                t[temp]++;
            }
            nb /= 10;
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

My main:

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class Primary{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] tab;
        int nb = keyboard.nextInt();
        tab = UtilNumber.Occurence(nb);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; i++){
            if (tab[i] != 0){
                System.out.println(i+" is present "+tab[i]+" time(s).");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example when I enter 888 it should return 3, but instead it returns 30.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like instead of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < t.length ; i++){
   t[temp]++;
 }
```

you should just do

```
 t[temp]++;
```

Comment: You are right, I really don't know why I put that there in the first place.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write.

```
public static int [] occurence(long nb){
    int[] count = new int [10];

    for(;nb > 0;nb /= 10) 
        count[nb % 10]++;

    return count;
}
```